# What is the easiest way to test for class membership in coffeescript?

Tags: coffeescript

I'm looking for an equivalent of Ruby's `"blah".is_a?(String)` of Objective-C's `[@"blah" isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Do you want to test whether an object is descended from a particular class? Then you want the `instanceof` keyword. (It's not something added by CoffeeScript; it's a part of JavaScript.) CoffeeScript classes are set up so that if you write

```
class A
class B extends A
class C extends B
```

then the following is true:

```
(new A) instanceof A
(new B) instanceof B and (new B) instanceof A
(new C) instanceof C and (new C) instanceof B and (new C) instanceof A
```

Also, any object will return `true` for `instanceof Object`.

If you want to test the *specific* class that an object is an instance of, use `.constructor`. For instance,

```
(new B).constructor is B
```

or if you'd like to use a string,

```
(new B).constructor.name is 'B'
```

Comment: Special note, Constructor.name does not work if your code is minified

Answer (score 0):

It feels wrong for me to create an instance of a class. You never know, what parameters the constructor might expect.

So what I came up with is this:

```
class A
class B extends A

console.log B.__super__ is A.prototype# => true
```

Comment: This is not the equivalent of Ruby's `"blah".is_a?(String)`