# How to see if a class has been instantiated

Tags: javascript, class, coffeescript

Here's a code example

```
class person 
  constructor: (@name, @age) ->

bob = new person("bob", 11)

if person?
  alert "yes!"
else
  alert "no"
```

In this, I test if a person class was instantiated, and it alerts "yes!" like it's supposed to. Because bob is a person, and was instantiated.

But over here:

```
class person 
  constructor: (@name, @age) ->

if person?
  alert "yes!"
else
  alert "no"
```

I want this to alert "no", because no person was instantiated, and yet it still alerts "yes!"

So what is the correct way to test if a class has been instantiated.

CLARIFICATION:

I do not want to test and see what bob is. I want to see if ANY FORM OF PERSON WAS INSTANTIATED.

Comment: `person?` doesn't check if a person can be instantiated, but it a variable or function named `person` exists (and it does, it's your constructor).

Comment: i believe you meant `bob?`, not `person?`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the easiest way to test for class membership in coffeescript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933569/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-test-for-class-membership-in-coffeescript)

Comment: @jbabey you misunderstood my question. I want to see if the person class was instantiated in any way. No matter the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are testing to see if the person class is defined. This will accomplish what you want.

```
class person 
  constructor: (@name, @age) ->
    person.prototype.instantiated = true

if person.prototype.instantiated
  alert "yes!"
else
  alert "no"
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'instantiated' of undefined

Comment: cratonica you're right. It's an issue with my code in my bigger project. Thanks =)

Comment: couldn't you just append a boolean property to the `person` function? does it need to be on the prototype?

Answer (score 1):

Same as the answer above but with more coffeescript-like syntax:

```
class person 
  constructor: (@name, @age) -> person::instantiated = yes

bob = new person "bob", 11

if person::instantiated
  alert "yes!"
else
  alert "no"
```